# Which scripture discusses the rituals to be followed while entering into a rented house?

Tags: scripture, grihastha

There is a fundamental difference between an own house and a rented house. Own a house is intended to live throughout one's life and a rented house is meant to live for a particular span of time which can span from a few months to years.

I watched various videos, but no one is mentioning any name of any scripture.  And I also encountered differences in opinion, some say that warming milk before entering a rented house is recommended and others say that it should be prohibited in a rented house.

In this context, I want to know a scripture that explains in detail the rituals or rules to be followed before entering a rented house.

Comment: I’d like to know this too. Am shifting to a rental and would like to do the proper stuffs. Hopefully someone replies to this 